# Extending Laravel base controller

Tags: php, laravel, session

I am a newbie in Laravel framework and I want to extend a base controller which in turn extends controller. However, I discovered that when I do that, my controller no longer recognises my session variables.

Here is my code

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Settings;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PermissionController;
use App\Fee;

class FeeController extends PermissionController
{

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        dd(session('userdata')['user_urls']);

        $data['title']="Fees";
        $data['fees']=Fee::all();
        return view('settings.fee.index',$data);
    }
```

And this is my PermissionController code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class PermissionController extends Controller {

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(Request $request) {
   if(!session('userdata')['user_urls']->contains($request->path())){
        dd(session('userdata')['user_urls']);
    }
}

}
```

But I realize that my `session('userdata')['user_urls']` becomes null at the PermissionController. But if I make FeeController to extend Controller, my session variables are intact.

I need to use the session variables for some control at the permission controller.

I am running Laravel 5.3 on a MAC OSX and PHP 7

Comment: Try removing the `__construct` from PermissionController. Also try with `parent::construct();` at the end of `__construct` method.

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve?  @Unche

Comment: @FelippeDuarte, I need the __construct method so that other child controller can inherit the features in the PermissionController.
Then, when I added parent::__construct(); I got an the following error

Cannot call constructor

Comment: @PassionInfinite
At login, each user has his permitted urls based on his/her user role. These urls are stores in session. So, from PermissionController, I want to check the url the use is trying to access and ensure that it is among the urls in session. Otherwise, redirect away

Comment: Yeah I know, it was just for testing purposes. If I'd remember, the session object is coupled with Request object, that may causing some issues with your classes/inheritance.

Comment: For this, I would like to advice you to make user policies and check the access. For more details visit this https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authorization @UcheNdukwe

Comment: @PassionInfinite, 
Thank you for that direction. but is there no way of extending controllers in laravel? Apart from the default Controller

Comment: Are you able to retrieve session in PermissionController?
Also Show route which is pointing to these controllers.
 @UcheNdukwe

Comment: @PassionInfinite
No. I am not able to retrieve session in PermissionController.

This is the Route
Route::get('create/fee','Settings\FeeController@create');

However, I am tending towards using Middleware to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the same problem with middleware. I have created a middleware that takes care of the authorization of requests by checking the session to ensure that the controller action being accessed is available in session.

This is the middleware

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class PermissionMiddleware
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $currentAction = \Route::currentRouteAction();

    list($nothing,$route_action) = explode('App\Http\Controllers\\', $currentAction);

    $user_actions=session('userdata')['user_urls'];

    if((empty($user_actions))||!$user_actions->contains($route_action)){

        return redirect('denied');
    }
    return $next($request);
   }
}
```

This is the controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Settings;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PermissionController;
use App\Fee;

class FeeController extends Controller
{

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index(Request $request)
{


    $data['title']="Fees";
    $data['fees']=Fee::all();
    return view('settings.fee.index',$data);
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $data['title']='New Fee';
    return view('settings.fee.create',$data);
}
```

So, instead of using the routes (cos of some other reasons), I used the controller actions.
So, once a user logs in, all the controller actions he can access are loaded into session. When he tries to perform any action, the middleware, does the check to ensure he is allowed to perform that action. Otherwise, he is routed away.

So, I either add 'permission' to the routes middleware or call

`$this->middleware('permission')`

on the controller's construct method.

That is working for me now.

Thank you everybody for your contributions.

Answer (score 2):

I have figured out the problem. Actually, PermissionController is not registered in the web middleware group so that session is not persisting in the PermissionController. So the solution to your question is just make a trait named as Permission instead of the controller and use it in FeesContorller.

```
trait Permission{
    public function permission(Request $request) {
        if($request->session()->get('name') != null){
            echo "Hello World";
        }
    }
}
```

And FeesController like this:

```
class FeesController extends Controller
{
    use Permission;

    public function index(Request $request)
    {    
        $this->permission($request); // the method of the trait.
        echo "\n".$request->session()->get('name');
    }
}
```

**Output:**

**If the name attribute is set in session then :**

```
Hello World

Passion Infinite
```

**Otherwise**

```
No Output // null
```

Comment: This is an intelligent approach. However, I wish there is something more seamless than this. 
Here, I still have to inject Request into every method that must implement the authorization.